# Angularjs: nested ng-repeat freeze browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have been working with angularjs and to loop i m using nested ng-repeat

my code is like

```
<li ng:repeat="item in data"> // 5 items in data
        {{item.name}} 
         <li ng:repeat="gch in item.totalfamily"> // 10 items in totalFamily 
                      {{gch.name}}
                     </li>
        <ul>
            <li ng:repeat="child in item.children"> //5 items in children
               {{child.name}} has grant-children: 
                <ul>
                     <li ng:repeat="gch in item.totalfamily"> // 10 items in totalFamily 
                      {{gch.name}}
                     </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
           <li ng:repeat="child in item.grandchildren"> //5 items in children
               {{child.name}} has grant-children: 
                <ul>
                     <li ng:repeat="gch in item.totalfamily"> // 10 items in totalFamily 
                      {{gch.name}}
                     </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
```

issue with this code that it freeze browser for some seconds .

can some one guide me wats wrong in it . because in JS if loop is taking time we put them in set-timeout so it doesn't freeze browser . but how to do this in ng-repeat

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use the chrome debug panel to profile the page and see what's taking the most time.  How many DOM elements does this end up creating ultimately? Seems like maybe a 100 or so if I'm understanding the nesting correctly but if it's too many DOM elements it could just be slowing the rendering of the view.

Comment: Just wondering, why you're using the "item.totalfamily" repeatedly when the outer loop is referring the same items.

Comment: @Senthil wat u suggest how i wld do that .

Comment: @shaunhusain you are right it creates 100 of rows and then append it to DOM . but in my scenario i need to do it . it means i have to bear  this freezing cost

Comment: Definitely suggest playing with the profiling tools to see if you can glean more information out of what is taking the most time, I've built some web-apps where I add a large amount of DOM elements but it still performs relatively well (on mobile there can be a couple of seconds delay for the most complex pages but these have on the order of a few hundred DOM elements, really not the best design honestly).  Ideally create only what the user can see and your in better shape but with only 100 or so li elements I wouldn't expect a slow down, can you reproduce in a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: i will try to produce plunkr . but it just freeze browser for 1 second or some time 2 second i will try to figure wat slowing down basically

Comment: The piece of code you posted is not valid HTML. Do you have correct order and nesting of <li> and <ul> tags?